# My jquery bootstrap-table removing enchanced data in cells on window resize

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table, window-resize

I using jquery [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/) on my site to show data from server. Before I pass data to table I create for every cell (that fits some contitions) a button.

So the process is:

1. Load / refresh / filter data
2. Put them in table
3. Add buttons to cells

But on resize window my button dissapear.
How can I prevent the bootstrap-table to remove that button?

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation - event [onResetView](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/#onresetview).

Bootstrap-table fires this event on window-resize and/or device rotated. Table takes original datapassed on load and redraw itself.

Fill you table with data and add buttons.

```js
$table.bootstrapTable('load', rows);  // set rows (data) to table
addYourButton();                      // add your button, init events, transform cells...
```

And add hook on event **reset-view.bs.table**

```js
$table.on('reset-view.bs.table', () => addYourButton());
```

Be sure to `addYourButton()` will do transform only once. You can achieve this with add some class on cell for example.

Reset-view event is called every time you resize window or manipulate table content. But sometimes table content is not redrawed - so your button could be added multipletimes.